# JavaScript moment format date string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using the Moment JavaScript library to take a date from my jQuery UI date picker. The date picker is currently using a format of `mm/dd/YYYY` in order to display a value to a user, so today would show as: `12/17/2013`. I need to submit this date in an XHR request using the format `YYYYmmdd` so the example above would turn into `20131217`. I tried using Moment like this:

```
var t_date = moment($("#datepicker").attr('value').replace('/', '-'), "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

The result for `t_date` however, comes out to be a large double, almost like a unix timestamp. At that point, I'm not entirely sure how to have Moment convert it to the string result I need above so I can embed it into a RESTful URL for my XHR request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function:

```
var t_date = moment($("#datepicker").attr('value').replace('/', '-'),'MM-DD-YYYY')
                     .format('YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Seems to get close to getting it right. When I have `12/09/2013` as my date, it's being formatted to `20201209`, something is messing up the year

Comment: Never mind, just had to add two more Y's to the first formatter. Otherwise your solution is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Curious why this solution if you're already implementing moment.js?